# Export to Excel using ASP Classic/Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've created a basic ASP page test.asp and code below.

---

```
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
        <table border="1px" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

---

I'm calling this ASP page from javascript by clicking button from html page, but excel report not opening.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/myweb/test.asp?, true);
```

When I open the same `test.asp` page directly, excel report opens perfectly. Not sure what I'm missing when calling using javascript? Please help.

---

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console (F12 in Chrome) ?

Comment: No errors in the console. By the way, this is the form below i call javascript function

Comment: <form name="dwnrepform" action="" Method="GET">
  <input type="button" name="Dwnld_Rprt" value="Download Report" onClick="DownloadRep();">
 </form>

Comment: Try redirecting to the ASP page: `window.location.href = "http://localhost/myweb/test.asp";`

Comment: Thank you Mike, it works. Will i'm able to pass parameter value to test.asp using window.location.href command?

Comment: Yes - its just a URL: `window.location.href = "http://localhost/myweb/test.asp?a=1&b=2";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a javascript redirect:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/myweb/test.asp?a=1&b=2";
```